# Trancription speech to text for two persons over the microfone (speech to text azure cognitive services)

Tags: azure, speech-to-text

I'm trying to transcribe a `real-time`conversation two persons over the microphone with `Azure's SpeechToText` cognitive service. The question is which scenario from cognitive service samples fit the best for that (I assume that for this scenario `speech_recognize_continuous` sample but I didn't find such a case for microphone only from the file) and is it possible to split results of speaking for each speaker.

The result of this demo should be like this:

```
    Person 1:
    Person 2:
    Person 1:
    Person 1:
    ....
```

Speech_recognition_language="de-DE"

What is the best way to show this conversation on Windows OS?

Answer (score 0):

There is a quickstart for doing speach from microphone to text here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/speech-to-text-from-microphone?tabs=dotnet%2Cx-android%2Clinux%2Cjava-runtime&pivots=programming-language-csharp

To do what you are trying to do you would have to run a program like this for each microphone, then each of these programs would have to report the text to a central location to print out the conversation.

Comment: Actually, in this scenario, two persons talk using one microphone. Is it possible in this kind of scenario separate users? I also tried quickstart, you sent me and I am not sure, should I use speech_recognize_continuous scenario_from_microphone ( I unfortunately I haven't seen this in the tutorial ) or some other scenario?

Comment: To do that you would need the program to recognize the voice of the person. Azure has a speach recognition API https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speaker-recognition/